# Preventing a class's function attributes from being passed self as the first arg

Tags: python, oop, syntax

Okay, so I've got a class where one of the attributes is a callback function. Problem is, whenever I call it from within the class (e.g. as `self.function_attr()`, it gets passed `self` as the first argument. Here's an idea of what I'm working with:

```
def callback(a, b):
    # do something with a, b

class A:
    def __init__(self, callback):
        self.callback = callback
        self.callback(1, 2) # Raises a TypeError: takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)
```

I'm not willing to write each callback function to take `self` as a first argument. I wrote a decorator that works around the issue:

```
def callback_decorator(func):
    def newfunc(self, *args, **kw):
        return func(*args, **kw)
    return newfunc
```

but I'm wondering if there's anything better.

Basically, my question is, how can I call instance attributes of my class which are functions without them being passed `self` as the first argument?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to make it a staticmethod when you bind it to the class.

```
def callback(a, b):
    # do something with a, b

class A:
    def __init__(self, callback):
        # now it won't get passed self
        self.callback = staticmethod(callback)
        self.callback(1, 2)
```

or

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, callback):
        self.callback(1, 2)

    # now it won't get passed self
    callback = staticmethod(callback)
```

Comment: This is better than what I've been doing. Definitely reduces code duplication.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, a wrapper (like your decorator) is the simplest way to go. Since you already have an object in which to store the function, I wouldn't bother with a decorator. (Note I've inherited from `object`, which is something you should probably be doing unless you specifically **want** old-style class behaviour.)

```
class A(object):

    def __init__(self, callback):
        self._callback = callback
        self.callback(1,2)


    def callback(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self._callback(*args, **kwargs)
```

This behaves as you'd expect:

```
>>> def f(x, y):
...     print "X: %s, Y: %s" % (x,y)
... 
>>> mya = A(f)
X: 1, Y: 2
```

Comment: yeah, my actual classes are new-style, my example just might not be on some older Python versions :)